# Android Camera ViewPoint

Tags: android, camera

is it possible to move programmatically the viewpoint of an android phone camera?

I know that it is possible to get the angle view:

getVerticalViewAngle()
getHorizontalViewAngle()

I want to change the view angle in order to take different shots without having to move the camera.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `setRotation (int rotation)`

This function sets the clockwise rotation angle in degrees relative to the orientation of the camera.

```
mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I need to move the field of view of the camera. How can I achieve this in an Android device camera? Thank you.